# Parsing .dxf through a request to the ArcGIS server REST API

Tags: arcgis-server, api

I have data in the DXF file. 
Can I parse the data and get response in an json by querying to the ArcGIS server (REST API)?

Comment: what kind of data are in the DXF file (which you want to parse)??

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you referring to point, line, polygon data, the best way (in my opinion) is:

- to convert the DXF data to shp or feature datasets in geodatabase (follow this: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000007258)
- publish them as a service in the server with enabled querying
- Finally you can get the required json by querying to the ArcGIS server (REST API). This might help: https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/query-feature-service-.htm